# Offline/Desktop Application that supports Send & Receive SMS using AT Commands in C#

Tags: c#, bulksms, smslib

I would like to build an offline desktop application that could carry out the basic sms functions with the usage of a GSM modem. I currently have a HUAWEI modem which was given to me by the telco company to perform wireless surfing and sms messaging services.

Does anyone have a sample project that i could reference to.

Was intending on using dll libraries such as SMSLib and GSMCommunication Libraries but was fearful of the potential bugs and incompatibility issues that it might be carrying. Hence, i am learning the various AT commands but do not know exactly how to program it in Visual Studios. Hope you could advise me on it.

Answer (score 0):

I was using ActiveExprerts SMS and MMS Toolkit, they have a good example on how you develop stuff from it and it supports a lot of GSM Modems, Mobile Phone and SMPP SMSC Providers.  If you need further help I have an old project which I implemented but its in VB.  Have a try and let me know its in www.activexperts.com.